# mysql date format conversion, stored procedure or php?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I need to convert dates from 
`DD Month, YYYY`
to `YYYY-MM-DD` that will be stored in a MySQL table.
I'm performing this with a PHP function, but I wonder if it's better practice to have it modified by the db itself. Stored procedure, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd handle it in the PHP. It's simpler if you always pass `date` values to the database in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I'd recommend not muck with the database just to convert string formats, whether that's an extra roundtrip to the database to do a conversion, or whether the conversions are done in the SQL.

There's plenty enough work to get the database code right.

If you do a separate call to do the conversion, that's the overhead of an extra round trip to the database, and all the PHP code to prepare a statement, bind parameters, execute, retrieve a resultset.

And your suggestion of adding a stored procedure, that's unnecessary cruft in the database; another object that has to be maintained, possibly in multiple databases.

If you do the conversion in SQL, that adds extra function calls, and complexity... what should the database do with invalid date values `'Feb 30, 2014'`. Is the handling appropriate for your application, and how will the behavior be influenced by MySQL settings.

I think you'd be much better off handling the conversion and validation in PHP, where you have more control.

---

With that said, it is possible to do conversions in MySQL. Easiest is to use the `STR_TO_DATE` function. You do need to specify the format of the string, and the function can return a NULL when it can't figure out what date is intended, and it return "invalid" date values, e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE('Frumiest 22, 2011','%M %d, %Y')    = NULL
STR_TO_DATE('February 30, 2012','%M %d, %Y')    = '2012-02-30'
```

How an "invalid date" value is handled and gets stored in a DATE column depends on the version of MySQL, whether "strict" mode is enabled, the setting of `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` variable, etc.

Comment: Great, I was expecting this kind of opinion as a response. I'm trying to decide which approach would be better for me, the code is getting complex and I was thinking in putting some of the logic on the Db side.

Comment: @Juan Pablo: The actual :conversion: from one format to another `"mon d, yyyy"` to `"yyyy-mm-dd"` shouldn't be more than a couple of lines of code, either a call to a `strtotime` (or a DateTime object). The coding to handle a return of "false" is where the real work is, i.e. what does your app do with an invalid date. If you were to make a database call, it could return a NULL value, and you still have the same issue to deal with.

Comment: I already had the conversion working in php, but I was wondering what practice would be best. The date is coming from a javascript date picker, and the validation is performed client side so there should be no invalid dates

Comment: @Juan Pablo: Can you set the format on the client? e.g. **`datepicker.({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })`**. (Does that not work? Or are you referencing that value on the client or server, somewhere  that the value needs to be in the locale setting of the client.) I think best practice is to validate on the client (for speed and convenience of the user) and to also validate on the server (to catch unscrupulous users from bypassing checks, and sending a nefariously modified request (ala "little bobby tables" (http://xkcd.com/327/ ) but that can be a lot of extra work.

Comment: yeah, I'm referencing the value `yyyy-mm-dd` (stored) and to avoid insanity, we chose to display it like `dd month, yyyy`. As the interface will be used in the US and Latin America, it's probably the less confusing format. Anyways, several precautions were taken to avoid injection, using prepared statements, etc.

Comment: @JuanPablo: It sounds like you're meeting the needs of the client, and doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `Table` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `Table` 
SET `date` = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d %M, %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.